# angular.js Table Filtering

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to create a table with a filter at the top of each column.

I am unable to figure out why the Any filter is working but not the individual colum filters.

I have the code @ http://plnkr.co/edit/6ghH02

I have also tried to compile the element after setting the ng-model but it did not work.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you get rid of the directive and use the ng-change attribute of the input[text] like so:

```
function TestController ($scope) {
    $scope.valueChanged = function (name, value) { 
        if (!$scope.search) {
            $scope.search = {};
        }
        $scope.search[name] = value;
    }
};

<body ng-controller="TestController">

<th ng-repeat="sortName in columnNames">
    <input type=text ng-model="value" ng-change="valueChanged(sortName, value)">
</th>
```

The short version of the answer as to why your original code doesn't work is that [ngRepeat creates a new scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) and the value in ng-model must be an assignable variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ryan pointed out, ng-repeat's nested scopes are the trick.  An alternative to writing a controller method is to use the $parent property of the child scope to access the search property in the parent scope:

```
<th ng-repeat="sortName in columnNames">
   <input type=text ng-model="$parent.search[sortName]"></th>
```

As in @Ryan's solution, a directive is not needed.
However, the additional search properties needed to be created/initialized:

```
<div ng-init="search.name = ''; search.phone = ''"></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wT34vh?p=preview